# Can I switch database with mysql_select_db?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect, mysql-select-db

Will this works, or should I disconnect first?

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('DB1');
//Code... 
//Now I need to change of db
mysql_select_db('DB2');
//More code...
```

I know mysql() is being deprecated, but I'm working with a old (not so much) system. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: just one recommendation. don't use the ancient `mysql` functions. use `mysqli` instead

Comment: @deceze Not yet. I'm a little busy for now. I'm still thinking about my next activity.

Comment: @aacanakin As I told, all of this system was used the mysql(). I can't change this.

Comment: @user2132073 - So lets get this straight - You do not have a particular problem that you have encountered. just on the off chance you post a question. I just hope you do not treat your co-workers in the same fashion. Well -1 for that

Answer (score 1):

The documentation say yes:

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

All queries will run on the current active database, at this case DB2.

**Sets the current active database** on the server that's associated with the **specified link identifier**. **Every subsequent call to mysql_query() will be made on the active database.**

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading the docs now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in sql like

```
SELECT `database`.`table`.`value` FROM `database`.`table`
```

Comment: This would mean she has to update each SQL query.

Comment: I know, but I'd lose so many time re-writing the querys.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) say:

> Sets the current active database on the server that's associated with the specified link identifier. Every subsequent call to mysql_query() will be made on the active database.

So yes. I guess it is comparable to a `use <database>` command on the client.

Comment: I see. Thanks. For a moment, I've forgotten the docs.

Answer (score 0):

you can have more than one active connection

```
$db1=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('DB1', $db1);

$db2=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('DB2', $db2);

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table", $db1);
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table", $db2);
```

Comment: see Bart Friederichs link indentifier answer